# R packages for text mining - beginner level

Tags: text-processing, r

I am looking for a simple to use R package that will allow me to:

1. Analysis a chunk of text data for frequency
2. Easily allow me to exclude common terms e.g. "and" "yes"
3. Allow for frequency analysis of linked words e.g." invoice unpaid" or "rejected by customer"

I'm looking for something that allows a beginning level R user to use. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[tidytext](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytext/index.html) allows you to do that.

There is also a free book on `tidytext` at https://www.tidytextmining.com/index.html.

1. Count word frequency:

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)

somewords <- "the lorem ipsum text with some common words.. very common words can be found quite often. these are often commonly used words enmeshed with lorem ipsum."

tibble(somewords) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, somewords) %>%
  group_by(word) %>%
  count() %>%
  arrange(desc(n))
```

2. Exclude common words

```
tibble(somewords) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, somewords) %>%
  filter(!word %in% stop_words$word)
```

3. Find common word combinations

```
bigrams <- tibble(somewords) %>%
  unnest_tokens(bigram, somewords, token = "ngrams", n = 2)

bigrams <- bigrams %>%
  count(bigram, sort = TRUE)
```